# Decripting RSA in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rsa

I am trying to figure out an easy way to decode a RSA cipher, that is using (p,q,e,c) as its variables were e is the private key.

If you you know anything about this please tell me!

Comment: erm ... i suppose you were not too lazy to type "python rsa" into google which would have lead you to this: http://stuvel.eu/rsa ... can you be more precise? what information you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a python-rsa module for encrypting/decrypting RSA. Check http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/usage.html for documentation and examples. Here's a small example from docs:

Bob generates a keypair, and gives the public key to Alice. This is done such that Alice knows for sure that the key is really Bob’s (for example by handing over a USB stick that contains the key).

```
>>> (bob_pub, bob_priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
```

Alice writes a message

```
>>> message = 'hello Bob!'
```

Alice encrypts the message using Bob’s public key, and sends the encrypted message.

```
>>> crypto = rsa.encrypt(message, bob_pub)
```

Bob receives the message, and decrypts it with his private key.

```
>>> message = rsa.decrypt(crypto, bob_priv)
>>> print message
```

hello Bob!